# solc_version not working on VS Code (Mac OSX)

Tags: solidity, python, visual-studio-code, py-solc-x

I tried running the code below and gave me the error message (bottom of post).

```
with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()
    print(simple_storage_file)

# Compile our Solidity

compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleSotrage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*" : {"*" : ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}                    
            }
        }
    }    
    solc_version = "0.6.0"
)
print(compiled_sol)
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
File "deploy.py", line 19
    solc_version = "0.6.0"
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
jeremyadamananto@Jeremys-MBP web3_py_simple_storage %
```

*Side note: When installing py-solc-x or checking pip --version, I have to use pip3 instead of pip. Not sure if this may or may not be an issue.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are writing is incorrect JavaScript syntax.

JavasScript objects use `:` as the notation to make key-value pairs.